# Ffmpeg amv conversion

Tags: ffmpeg, conversion

I have a friend in an institution. He only has access to a SanDisk sansa clip sport mp3 player, but it has been modded to run firmware for a Ruizu X10 mp3 player.

It can display videos in amv format only, due to the weak processor.

He is converting MP4 videos on an Android phone using ffmpeg, using the following commands:

-c:v amv -c:a adpcm_ima_amv -pix_fmt yuvj420p -vf
"scale=148:128:force_original_aspect_ratio=dec reas e,crop=128:in_h:10:0,pad=160:128:32:-1:c
olor=black" -vstrict -1 -r 30 -ac 1 -ar 22050 -block_size 735

However, the video quality is poor, blurry.

We are completely new to this and don't understand the code above.

Can you guys please help tweak the code to deliver better video quality that the weak mp3 processor can still handle?

If possible, please just tell us what to type in the ffmpeg template box, because we are very new.

The command to resize the video is necessary because the firmware on the mp3 player was made for a larger screen.

Maybe 30fps is unnecessary? Not sure

Thank you all!!!

Comment: Try adding `-q:v 4 -qmin 1 -qmax 16`. Experiment with the `q:v` value.

Comment: Thanks so much. Will try. Should I also experiment with the qmin and qmax values?

Comment: qmin can't go lower. And a higher qmax is only needed in order to slightly reduce file size.

Comment: Thanks, I tried altering these -q:v values by adding "-q:v 4" to the very end of my script and trying different values. All the videos were the same file size and looked identical. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: These are output options so they go before the output path.